# If widowed aunt remarries, is her husband "uncle"?

Tags: kinship-terms

My mother's brother's wife Louise has always been *Aunt Lou* to me; her husband, my Uncle Bob, died young, but we still called her Aunt Lou.

After many years she has now re-married. Is her second husband my Uncle Jim or not?

Comment: "Husbang" - typo, or awesome neologism?

Comment: In Anglophone areas, such kinship titles are a matter of personal or family convention. There's a technical term for the relationship -- there's a technical term for every possible kinship relation -- but only anthropologists use them. What that all means is that your aunt and you and her new husband can negotiate a solution that feels comfortable for all of you.

Comment: So, [apparently](http://www.pinterest.com/jbianca15/husbang-material/) this term already exists...

Comment: Have fun. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology

Comment: I have mentioned (postings *passim*) that when I worked in Japan, the office staff even used to refer to the old guy who acted as security officer, odd-job man, and general factotum, as 'Uncle'. These things are strictly cultural, and there are no hard and fast rules.

Comment: Except for ethnographers.

Comment: Wouldn't he be your step-uncle?

Comment: I had an aunt, a widow who remarried, her second husband was always "Beppe" (Joe) to me, and never uncle. I knew and loved my uncle for over 30 years, and not for one instant did I think I was being disrespectful to my aunt. I think it's easier to accept a new "Uncle" when you are still a child. Of course much depends on Aunt Lou's husband, if he is withdrawn and distant (as "Beppe" was) then he will never be really part of the family. If he participates in all family functions then people will either call him Uncle Jim, out of affection, or just plain Jim.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of culture and how close you interact with him. Technically, I dont think he is your uncle anymore. He is a new guy in a separate family and doesn't have to do anything with being your uncle. But if you are still in close contact with your aunt and want to stay with her in good terms, why not. I'd call him uncle. And there's nothing wrong with it. I have seen people calling strangers uncles just because they know their father.